# Can all the servers use HTTP1.1 already

Tags: http, http-headers, network-protocols, http-1.1

I wanted to know if all the servers could already communicate with HTTP1.1.

And what happens if one of the two servers does not support HTTP1.1 and the other tries to communicate with this protocol ?

Thanks for your explanations :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every server that you will use supports and makes use of HTTP 1.1. It came out before the year 2000 so you are pretty safe.

[HTTP 1.1 Protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)